# Do mysqli_result need an alive connection to seek results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We noticed that a call to our API endpoint usually have multiple duplicated MySQL queries for `SELECT` statements (sometimes hundreds). So we decided to create a hashmap to store the
`mysqli_result` and check if a given query has already been done and return the result saved in our map.

My question is: do `mysqli_result` maintain a reference to our connection? Would this actually help us to avoid overloading our database with queries that have already been requested unnecessarily? If the `mysqli_result` is too big, could this overflow the memory for our `fpm` process?

What I want to know basically is what approach is better:

- For query A, reuse `mysqli_result` object everytime I need it;
- Redo query A everytime I need it.

Comment: Why would you need to buffer `mysqli_result`? Just buffer the data. Only data, nothing else. The mere fact that you are asking about `mysqli_result` suggests that you have problems with your DB abstraction class, because `mysqli_result` should only be an intermediate object and should not be exposed to your application logic.

Comment: @Dharman It is not exposed to our application logic

Comment: Can you show us the code you are talking about? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know if caching a `mysqli_result` object on our DB abstraction is OK.

Comment: You can't   reuse  mysqli result wihout a connection  ..if you want reuse several time the data result  ..  you must store somewhere  .. (not in db if you don't want connection)

Comment: Is it better to reuse the same `mysqli_result` object several times or is it better to redo the whole Query and generate a new `mysqli_result` object being that both queries are the same?

Comment: If you can preserve in a safe way the result you can reuse the data as you prefer ..  but how do you  preserve the data??? whiiout a db  ... ??   ..In memory?  how you share memory between proecess .. ??  on file system ??  have you an  efficent way for manage this??

Comment: This would be only session based. So I do an http access to my endpoint, and the code needs to run Query A 5 times, is it better to rerun the same query all 5 times or is it better to store the mysqli_result from the first run and reuse it for the other 4 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_result()` requires neither a connection to MySQL nor a `mysqli` object once the results are fetched from MySQL.

**Caveat:** The above only applies to the buffered queries. If you are using unbuffered resultsets then `mysqli_result` requires an open mysqli connection to fetch the data otherwise you will receive an error saying:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_result::fetch_all(): Error while reading a row in ...

However, this error message can only happen when you close the connection when using unbuffered queries. e.g.

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM Users LIMIT 1', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$mysqli->close();
$res->fetch_all();
```

Even though `mysqli_result` requires a valid connection when creating an instance of it, it only needs the connection to fetch the data. The second parameter in the `mysqli_result::__construct()` is used to decide whether the resultset should be buffered in PHP or stored on MySQL server and fetched row by row. When you create an instance of `mysqli_result` you need to pass an instance of `mysqli` as the first parameter.

```
// Execute query on MySQL server
$res = $mysqli->real_query('SELECT id FROM Users LIMIT 1');
// Create the result object. 
// The second argument can be MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT for buffered result or MYSQLI_USE_RESULT for unbuffered.
$res = new mysqli_result($mysqli, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

// If MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT was used then you can close mysqli here.
unset($mysqli); // or $mysqli->close(); or both
$data = $res->fetch_all();

// If MYSQLI_USE_RESULT was used then you can't close mysqli yet.
// unset($mysqli);
$data = $res->fetch_all();
```

Buffering of SQL queries is a rather complex task and it would be better to avoid duplicate calls rather than implementing caching. Try to refactor your code so that it does not call the same `SELECT` query multiple times during the execution of your script.

There is also a pre-made solution for this, although not very popular. [Mysqlnd query result cache plugin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php)

And as always remember that:

> premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Thanks @Dharman, that's pretty much what we are doing, but without using this plugin. I'll take a look on it to see how we can add it to our application.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano I added clarification