# How do i store / serialize php returned mysqli_query results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to store results returned from mysqli_query as cache, so if the same "SELECT" statement is executed, it will get from the cache instead of going through mysql server BUT the following code, no matter what i tried with serialize / json_encode,decode or even just storing output as variable, i can't do

```
        $row = $this->result->fetch_object();
```

Code as below. Does anyone know why? How do I just store the returned results and re use it? it does not work with $this->result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);

```
                global $dbcache;
//                      $this->result = mysqli_query( $dbh, $query );
                if (isset($dbcache[$query])){
                        $this->result = json_decode($dbcache[$query]);
//                        echo 'JSON? = '.$query.'<br>'.$dbcache[$query];
                }else{
//                      echo ' === '.$dbcache[$query].' === '."\n";
                        $this->result = mysqli_query( $dbh, $query );
                        //$dbcache[$query] = serialize($this->result);
                        $dbcache[$query] = json_encode($this->result);
//                      echo 'Serialize? = '.$query."\n".hash('sha3-512' , $query).'<br>';
                }
```

Comment: Can you clean up the code in question a little bit please?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745018/do-mysqli-result-need-an-alive-connection-to-seek-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store `mysqli_result` object for longer than necessary to fetch the data. It is only meant to be used as a temporary object used for fetching the data from MySQL. Cache the values instead.

```
if (isset($dbcache[$query])) {
    $this->result = $dbcache[$query];
} else {
    $dbcache[$query] = $this->result = $dbh->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

However, I would be wary of how useful this approach is with prepared statements. You would probably want to make the key a combination of the query and parameters. For example:

```
$key = serialize([$query, ...$params]);
if (isset($dbcache[$key])) {
    $this->result = $dbcache[$key];
} else {
    //prepare bind execute
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    if ($params) {
        $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    // Fetch results into multidimensional array
    $dbcache[$key] = $this->result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

You really should abstract from using mysqli functions in your application code. If you are building some kind of abstraction layer than you should only return the data to the application and use mysqli only internally. Using my recommended approach you would be accessing the data as a normal array; no more `fetch_object()` methods. Of course, this requires that you change your application code, but it is a good idea to do so. I would also strongly advise to start using PDO.

Comment: the results i'm getting from


$dbcache[$query] = $this->result = $dbh->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

this is totally different from
    
            $this->result = mysqli_query( $dbh, $query );

Comment: need solution for caching mysqli_query( $dbh, $query ); exactly. i've tried your code and it does not work. how do i cache mysqli_query( $dbh, $query ); properly?

Comment: Why do you need to cache `mysqli_result` object? As I said you only need the data, not the intermediary object.

Comment: i need to cache the return results of mysqli_query( $dbh, $query ); all of my program is written as such. the application logic behind to convert to your method will be too much work. can anyone provide examples of how to do $this->result = mysqli_query( $dbh, $query );  caching?

Comment: You can't cache this object. Why do you need to cache anything at all. Either cache the data or don't cache anything at all.

Comment: so how do i cache the returned value of mysqli_query object?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns an object of class `mysqli_result`. That object is used to retrieve the data from MySQL server. This object cannot be serialized or stored in a file. [It requires an open connection to MySQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62745218/1839439) However, you can fetch the complete data from MySQL and store it in PHP arrays. Storing this in a file probably does not make much sense, since you could fetch that data once more from MySQL instead of reading from a file, which in turn defeats the whole purpose of caching the data. So, Why do you want to cache anything?